# Get path parameter on Next.js API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following file

`pages/api/[slug]/[uid].ts`

And I want to get the `slug` and the `uid` on the body of my handler, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `useRouter()` custom hook provided by the next for accessing query params in NextJs. It will return an object which will contain details of the url loaded, including the query params. The params will be stored within `query` key in the returned object. The `query` itself has an object as value, where key is the param name (here `slug` and `uid`) and its dynamic values as the values.

Then we can make use of the object destructuring for drilling into the required params.

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug, uid } = router.query;
```

For accessing single param, we can do as follows,

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const slugValue = router.query.slug;
  const uidValue = router.query.uid;
```

Comment: This solution is on the client side when trying to get the route parameters, but the OP was asking on the server side using under the /api directory.

Answer (score 8):

You can access it with `req.query`
Just console.log it and see docs for more https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted one produces an error complaining about illegal use of hooks.